# Exposing C# Code to VBA GetAutomationMethod Error

Tags: c#, vba, excel, com

I am a relatively new coder and have never worked with C# or VBA before. I am currently trying to expose my C# code to VBA. I have been following the [MSDN guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608604.aspx) on how to do that.

I am running into an error when it comes to overriding my method:

```
public class AsynchronousClient : IAsynchronousClient {
    protected override object GetAutomationObject(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

The error is:

> 'AsynchronousClient.GetAutomationObject()': no suitable method found to override.

I have been able to extract the interface and added the `COMVisibleAttributes` to my interface.

Any help or additional guidance on how to amend the code would be appreciated.

Comment: Where comes from IAsynchronousClient? the error states that interface does not have a function named GetAutomationObject with the same parameters to be overriden.

Comment: That how-to page is specific to VSTO "document-level projects".  Pretty doubtful that's what you are actually trying to do.  You must override GetAutomationObject() on your host item, not on a class that you need to expose a property of the host item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, the steps you're following are specific to the VSTO technology, not for creating a DLL to use with VBA. Quite honestly, if you've never coded in either language before, this is probably not the best thing to start with...

Start with a Class project. You need GUIDs. You need an Interface, which your class needs to implement. And you need to specify how the class should work with the Interface. It needs to be set to the Type "None" for the Intellisense, etc. to work. The DLL needs to be COM-registered, as well.

Here's some test code I use, to give you an idea how the code part looks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using vbForm = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
using office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

//[assembly: Guid("B5C4D7F5-C9B2-491e-91BA-63C208959190")]

namespace COM_ClassLib_CS
{

    [Guid("BF78EB64-F59B-4086-9FC5-B87AA2002F4F")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IVBAExtensions
    {
        string getTest(object app);
        void formData(object formControl);
        void passWordDoc(object doc);
        object[,] returnArray();
        string returnString();
    }

    [Guid("EC0B623E-E8A0-4564-84FB-2D8D149C8BA7")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class VBAExtensions : IVBAExtensions
    {
        public VBAExtensions()
        {
        }

        //test using late-binding
        public string getTest(object app)
        {
            object xlApp = app.GetType().InvokeMember("Application", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,
                app, null);
            object nm = xlApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,
                xlApp, null);
            string appName = nm.ToString();
            object isReady = xlApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Ready", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,
                xlApp, null);
            string sReady = isReady.ToString();
            return sReady;
        }

        //test calling from a UserForm, passing control as argument
        public void formData(object formControl)
        {
            //string data = "";
            vbForm.TextBox t = formControl as vbForm.TextBox;
            t.Text = "test";
            //return data;
        }

        //test passing doc object and accessing its Window
        public void passWordDoc(object doc)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document WordDoc = doc as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
            WordDoc.ActiveWindow.Caption = "Tested!";
        }

        //test returning an array to VBA calling procedure
        public object[,] returnArray()
        {

            //object[] array = new object[2] {"a", "b"};
            object[,] array = new object[2, 2];
            array[0, 0] = "a";
            array[0, 1] = "1";
            array[1, 0] = "b";
            array[1, 1] = "2";
            return array;
        }

        //test returning a string to VBA calling procedure
        public string returnString()
        {
            return "AbC";
        }

    }
}
```

For more information you can reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I think I have added the appropriate attributes (the ProgId, Guid) and I think removing the protected override method object is the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AsynchronousClient` class is implementing the `IAsynchronousClient` interface, which I presume looks like this:

```
public interface IAsynchronousClient
{
    object GetAutomationObject();
}
```

You would implement it like this:

```
public class AsynchronousClient : IAsynchronousClient
{
    public object GetAutomationObject()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The error message says exactly what the problem is: there's nothing to `override` there. You use the `override` method when you're implementing `abstract` or `virtual` methods, not interface members.

Remove the `override` keyword and you'll be good. Below snippets show situations where `override` would be applicable:

```
public abstract class AsynchronousClientBase
{
    public abstract object GetAutomationObject();

    public virtual object GetFoo()
    {
        return null;
    }
}


public class AsynchronousClient : AsynchronousClientBase
{
    public override object GetAutomationObject()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public override object GetFoo()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

The MSDN article you linked to says to "Override the GetAutomationObject method of a host item class in your project" - this implies your type should be *derived* from a base class that defines a virtual or abstract `GetAutomationObject` method.